# Writing a string parser in JS for specific values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way of parsing a string for specific values in JavaScript. I've looked through other posts and find examples in C# and python, but I'm trying to find a good way to do it in JavaScript.

I will be receiving values matching this format:

```
#recordNum-1000 (Description: "Test", Date: "1/31/2021")
```

I want to be able to do these steps:

- If **#recordNum-** is found, I want to extract the number that follows it
- If parentheses are found after the number,

  - if there is a **Description**, I want to extract it's value, if not I should get **null**
  - if there is a **Date**, I want to extract it's value, if not I should get **null**

What is the best way of going about this? String manipulation? Regex matching? I was thinking of using string manipulation for it, but I wasn't sure if there's a more efficient preferred process. I'm pretty new to trying this so I wasn't sure how to go about it

Comment: Looks like a regular language, but we cannot tell with only a single example. Is there a formal specification of the format?

Comment: Part of the input looks a bit like JSON, but not quite. Strange that `"Description"` appears in quotes, but `Date` does not. Looks fuzzy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions will do the job.

I tested the following regex and they worked fine:

```
/recordNum-([0-9]{1,})
/Description":.{1,}"([A-z]{1,})"
/Date:.{1,}"(.{1,})"
```

You can try it online in [regular expression tester](https://regex101.com/)

[How to use RegEx in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for and is very helpful. The links are very helpful too. I'm hoping the 2nd link will help me understand how to edit it so I can do things like accept Descriptions with spaces. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cineno28, to accept Descriptions with any character you can use /Description":.{1,}"(.{1,})"